# What are the locations that contains market stalls in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

From memory, these cities:

> Whiterun,  Riften, Markath,  Solitude,  Windhelm

have market stalls, but are there other locations with market stalls that I have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot one city and it's Raven Rock from the second DLC.

Whiterun

Riften

**Raven Rock**

Markarth

Solitude

Windhelm

Answer (score 1):

Marketplace stalls can only be found in the five major cities of Skyrim, so your list is complete.
The vendors with market stalls are:

**Whiterun**

- [Carlotta Valentia](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Carlotta_Valentia)
- [Anoriath](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Anoriath)
- [Fralia Gray-Mane](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fralia_Gray-Mane)

**Riften**

- [Brand-Shei](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Brand-Shei)
- [Grelka](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Grelka)
- [Madesi](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Madesi)
- [Marise Aravel](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marise_Aravel)

**Markarth**

- [Kerah](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kerah)
- [Hogni Red-Arm](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hogni_Red-Arm)

**Solitude**

- [Addvar](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Addvar) (/[Greta](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Greta))
- [Evette San](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Evette_San)
- [Jala](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Jala)

**Windhelm**

- [Aval Atheron](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aval_Atheron)
- [Hillevi Cruel-Sea](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hillevi_Cruel-Sea)
- [Niranye](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Niranye)